# asymptotic growth of coefficients of two-variable power series

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, asymptotics, generating-functions

Suppose you have a function of two variables, say $f(x,y)$, that is nice enough to equal a power series $\sum_{m,n} a_{m,n}x^my^n$ in some region about the origin.

> Is there a rough asymptotic formula for $a_{m,n}$ based solely on $m$, $n$ and the singularities of $f$?

This question is essentially a two-dimensional version of the root test: if $f(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$, and $r$ is the modulus of the smallest singularity of $f$, then $a_n\sim r^{-n}$.

Two simple-but-contrasting examples are $f_1(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1-2x)(1-3y)}$ with $a_{m,n}=2^m3^n$ and $f_2(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-xy}$ with $a_{m,n}=0$ unless $m=n$ and then $a_{m,m}=1$.

> As a particular application, I am interested in approximating the coefficients of the rational function $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-y)^2-xy}$, which is the generating function of an array of numbers of combinatorial objects I am studying.

Comment: How are you defining "singularity of $f$"?

Comment: In the rational case, let's just say an $x,y$ pair so the numerator is non-zero and the denominator is zero.

Comment: I don't see $a_n \sim r^{-n}$ in the case $f(x) = 1/(1-x)^2.$ Also, $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ has no singularities on $\mathbb R$ but its MacClaurin series has radius of convergence $1.$

Comment: For $1/(1-x)^2$ the growth of the coefficients is linear, definitely sub-exponential, and for $1/(1+x^2)$ the coefficients are bounded by 1 in modulus. I think implicitly the domain for the singularities must be $\mathbb C$. The growth rate of $a_n\sim r^{-n}$ is a rough statement for, for instance, theorem 2.4.3 [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) or theorem IV.7 [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/book.pdf). In any case, I'd be  happy with an exponential estimate of the coefficients of the two-variable power series.

Comment: Well OK, but $\sim$ usually means asymptotic equivalence.

Comment: You're right. I'm using $\sim$ in the loose sense of "approximately equal".

Comment: In case you aren't already aware of this resource (Twenty combinatorial examples of asymptotics derived from multivariate generating functions): https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512548

Comment: @HughDenoncourt: That article looks like exactly what I was hoping for. I will study that for sure. Also, I see they have extended the article to an [entire book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1107031575/). Many, many thanks for the reference!

Comment: @RusMay: Excellent! I wasn't aware of the extension into a book.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Premantle and Wilson's ["Analytic Combinatorics in Several Variables"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/ACSV.pdf) is of help. Or Greenwood's dissertation ["Asymptotics of Bivariate Generating Functions with Algebraic Singulatities"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/Student-theses/Greenwood150424.pdf) looks like more focused on your specific problem.

Comment: I am definitely familiar with Pemantle and Wilson's ACSV book, but Greenwood's dissertation is new to me. I'm still learning the ACSV theory, so I'll take a look. Thanks so much.